# Scala Play handling JSON objects and arrays

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework

I am making a third party API call using Play WS to get back a JSON object with a list of objects. I want to iterate through this list and add a key/value to each item. I am new to Scala and typed languages, and it is really difficult to deal with JSON in Scala. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is what I have right now:

```
def getAll(filters: String) = Action.async { request =>
  val api_url = API_URL + "search?api_key=" + API_KEY + filters

  ws.url(api_url).get().map { response =>
    val body = response.body
    val json = Json.parse(body)
    val listings = (json \ "listings").get
  }

  // I want to iterate through listings, which is of type JsValue
  // And for each object, I want to add a key/value pair

  Ok(listings)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a JsonNode you have to cast it to ObjectNode to be able to add a property.
For example, having listings:
EDIT:

```
 listings.asInstanceOf[JsArray].value.map{ jsvalue =>
  (jsvalue.asInstanceOf[JsObject]) + ("extra" -> JsString("something"))
}
```

Comment: Or shorter version: `_.asInstanceOf[ObjectNode].put("key", "value")`

Comment: I tried this, but got this error: "value map is not a member of play.api.libs.json.JsValue"

Comment: You're right, I had a wrong assumption, I changed the solution. Accept if it works :)